# Convert ddmmyy date to datetime in sas

Tags: sas

I want to convert date type `12/09/1991` to `12sep1991 00:00:00` in `sas.tried` using multiple formats but it is not working.

I have also checked with converting to numeric format.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have an actual date value that is using the DDMMYY format to make it appear as 12/09/1991? Or do you have character variable with the value '12/09/1991'?

Comment: My first question would be why do you need to do this?  It may be that there are options available which mean you don't need this transformation.  If you do need to do it, then the solution from @Tom is the most efficient in SAS

Answer (score 2):

Dates are stored as the number of days since 1960. Datetime is stored as the number of seconds. There is not a format that can be used to display a date value as if it was a datetime value. You will need to convert the value instead.

You can use the `dhms()` function. Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

So if your current variable is named `date` you can make a new variable named `datetime`.

```
datetime=dhms(date,0,0,0);
format datetime datetime20. ;
```

You could assign the value back to the original variable because both date and datetime values are stored as numbers.

Answer (score -2):

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as timestamp),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual
```

Of course in the above the FF would also always be 000000

But if you have a timestamp variable you would not cast

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual
```

Comment: Any simple solution

Comment: Not sure how Oracle functions are going to help a SAS programmer.